# graphql-codegen problem with generating typescript interfaces from graphql interfaces

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I'm having a problem while generating TS interfaces from my graphQL schema.
My code:

```
export const userTypeDefs = gql`

  input SignUpRequestInput {
    name: String!
    password: String!
    role: Int!
  }

  interface SomeInter {
    name: String!
  }

  type Mutation {
    createUser(request: SignUpRequestInput): SomeInter
  }
`;
```

When I run server in my graphql playground I can see both `SignUpRequestInput` input and `SomeInter` interface, nevertheless when I run `graphql-codegen` script it only generates `SignUpRequestInput` interface and omits `SomeInter`

Script that I'm running:

```
graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml
```

codegen.yml:

```
overwrite: true
schema: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
documents: null
generates:
  src/interfaces/generated.ts:
    plugins:
      - 'typescript'
    config:
      skipTypename: true
      declarationKind:
        type: 'interface'
        input: 'interface'
        interface: 'interface'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: just use `type SomeInter`, not interface [not used/implemented] ?

Comment: I just prefer using `interface` over `type` :/

Comment: it's not typescript ... use types generally, use interfaces when needed

Comment: @xadm the point is, there might be some types that implement from that interface, he is asking for a reason

Comment: @xadm might as well just say "Stop coding, pay real engineers to code for you"